# Jquery .post() passing multiple variables not working

Tags: jquery, parameters, cakephp-2.0, .post

In my code below I'm trying to pass 2 parameters to an Ajax call,  however when loading the page, I'm getting a javascript error shown below. 
Note this error happens even before i attempt to trigger the ajax with a button click (the code shown below is in a working button click event handler code).

[image]

When I comment out the .post() block of code, the page loads fine without any javascript errors.
Below is the code. This is the first time i'm passing 2 parameters to ajax .post() after refering to this post on how to do it. [Sending Multiple variables with Jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688349/sending-multiple-variables-with-jquery-ajax)

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code? Both my alert statements work fine and display correct data. Note i'm using Cakephp so there's some cakephp syntax there.

```
       //Get the merchant config
        alert("you got here!");

        bookingdate = $(this).parent().parent().find("#bookingdate").serialize();
        merchant_id = $(this).parent().parent().find("#merchant_id").serialize();

        alert (bookingdate + " " + merchant_id);

        $.post( "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'MCP','action'=>'getMtRestaurant')); ?>", {bookingdate, merchant_id}, function() { 
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data.response);
            //parseddata = JSON.parse(data);
            $('.ajax_booking_edit').append(data);

        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "There was a problem retrieving the booking!" );
        })
        .always(function() {
            //alert( "finished (always)" );
        });
```

I'm showing below the alert popup that displays the bookingdate and merchant_id after being serialized.
[image]

Comment: You're combining php in jquery i.e. `<?php Router.....` which is wrong, you need to pass there url....

Comment: Hi,.. as i mentioned this is Cakephp code so and it outputs the correct URL in the .post() call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`serialize()` both of them together.

```
var bookingdate = $(this).parent().parent().find("#bookingdate"),
    merchant_id = $(this).parent().parent().find("#merchant_id"),
    filterdata = bookingdate.add(merchant_id).serialize();
$.post("<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'MCP','action'=>'getMtRestaurant')); ?>",
filterdata, function () {})
```

Answer (score 1):

A trick can be used, if passing one value works.

Example :

```
var msg = $arg1 + "--" + $arg2 + "--" + $arg3;

    $.post("../Php/test.php", { msg: msg },
                            function (result) {
                                alert(result);
                            });
```

In the php file do,

```
<?php
   $msg = $_POST['msg'];
   $ar = explode("--", $msg);
   //Now we have $ar[0] --> arg1, $ar[1] --> $arg2, $ar[2] --> $arg3
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending a POST through jQuery, you need to choose variable names for the variables you're using. The fix is simple, just change the row to:

```
$.post( "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'MCP','action'=>'getMtRestaurant')); ?>", {bookingDate: bookingdate, merchantId: merchant_id}, function() {
```